# GC.Collect does not call IronPython destructor

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I have a simple IronPython class which implements a destructor (`__del__`) and write some thing to the console 
in it. If there is not reference to the instance any more and i call `GC.Collect` for testing purpose, the destructor will never be called. Is this correct? Does the DLR/IP has it's own memory management on top of the clr/gc?

Comment: Not sure about destructors in Iron Python, but if they are like finalizers in C# then this might be some good reading http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/

Comment: I'm not positve and don't quote me on that (a consequence of not having to deal with destructors in .Net anymore) but I think that even in a pure C# App when you call GC.Collect there is no guarantee that the GC will fire immediatly.

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps a broader question than you realize.

The typical behaviour of a class with a finalizer is that the GC will move the item into a finalizer queue on collect. The queue of objects is processed separately (though you can call `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` to block until it completes). This means that the object is still rooted (there is a reference to it from the finalizer queue, even if not from your code!) and so will typically survive GC and be promoted to the next generation.

For this reason you might have to GC *twice* before your item is cleaned up. It also means that the finalizer will by definition occur at *some arbitrary time after your collect*. If you call `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`, though, you should see your finalizer called.

To avoid all this undesireable behaviour, it is typical to implement the `IDisposable` interface to explicitly handle cleanup of unmanaged resources. If you look at a typical [example implementation from documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx), you will see that the `Dispose` method typically calls `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`. This means that, if you dispose of the object *cleanly* in your code, the finalizer need not be called at all.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Even using `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` + `GC.Collect` does not call the constructor. (Using it in different variation and multiple times) This was also only for testing prupose, how the dlr react/work. Thank you for your nice and detailed answer!